# Iterating over a multidimensional BTreeMap

Tags: rust

I am using the [`toml`](https://crates.io/crates/toml) crate  to parse a `.toml` file which looks like this:

```
config = { option = "?" }


array = [
    { key1 = value1, key2 = value2, key3 = value3, key4 = value4 },
    { key1 = value1, key2 = value2, key3 = value3, key4 = value4 }
]
```

I have a `parser.rs` file which contains:

```
extern crate toml;

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ConfigParser<'a> {
    pub file: &'a str
}

impl<'a> ConfigParser<'a> {
    pub fn new(file: &'a str) -> ConfigParser {
        ConfigParser { file: file }
    }

    pub fn parse(&self) -> Option<BTreeMap<String, toml::Value>> {
        let mut config_string = String::new();
        File::open(self.file).and_then(|mut f| {
            f.read_to_string(&mut config_string)
        }).unwrap();

        return toml::Parser::new(&config_string).parse();
    }
}
```

and use it in my `main.rs` file like so:

```
extern crate toml;
mod parser;

fn main() {
    let config = parser::ConfigParser::new("config.toml").parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config)
}
```

which prints:

```
{"config": Table({"option": String("?")})
```

I tried iterating over the `config` like so:

```
for (key, value) in config {
    println!("{:?} {:?}", key, value)
}
```

which will produce:

```
"config" Table({"option": String("?")})
```

but this:

```
for (key, value) in config {
    for v in value {
        println!("{:?}", v)
    }
}
```

throws this error:

```
the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `toml::Value`
```

Answer (score 4):

The core issue is that a [`toml::Value`](http://alexcrichton.com/toml-rs/toml/enum.Value.html) is a *single value*. Thus, it doesn't make sense to iterate over it. That would be akin to iterating over a boolean.

A `Value` is an [enum](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/enums.html), which is a data type that can represent one of a fixed set of choices. in this case, it could be something like a `String` or a `Float` or a `Table`. Your example code shows that you have the `Table` variant. The `Value::Table` variant has a [`toml::Table`](http://alexcrichton.com/toml-rs/toml/type.Table.html) struct as the sole member. This type is just another `BTreeMap`.

You have prove to the compiler that you are able of handling the specific variant that you care about. Usually, this is done with a `match` or an `if let` statement. Once you verify that the variant is one you care about, you can continue to poke into the nested values:

```
extern crate toml;

use toml::{Parser, Value};

fn main() {
    let config_string = r#"config = { option = "?" }"#;
    let parsed = Parser::new(config_string).parse().unwrap();

    for (key, value) in parsed {
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", key, value);

        if let Value::Table(t) = value {
            for (key, value) in t {
                println!("{:?}, {:?}", key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to rust and I'm not sure if this is right but this is what I did to get it to work with the current version of toml (`toml = "0.5.9"`)

```rust
use toml::Value;

fn main() {
    let config_string = r#"config = { option = "?" }"#;
    let parsed: Value = toml::from_str(config_string).unwrap();

    for (key, value) in parsed.as_table().unwrap().iter() {
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", key, value);

        if let Value::Table(t) = value {
            for (key, value) in t {
                println!("{:?}, {:?}", key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster if you could take a look I'd appreciate it, no rush.